# View all site moderators, past and present

Tags: feature-request, moderators, users-page

I am not aware of any way to see all mods a site has had.  [Moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) and the [moderators page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) lists only the current mods.

There should be a page that displays all the moderators a site has had.
On my [home site](http://blender.stackexchange.com) we are having an election now and three of our four mods are not running. In the not too distant future users will forget, and new users will never know that these users served as moderators. We have already replaced a mod, and many users do not know who he was.

SE need a place to recognize the service of all mods, not just during their term.

I propose adding a link to the [moderators page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) that goes to a new  moderator page. Where all moderators that have served that site will be listed along with the time of their service.

Comment: Meanwhile, the site's users can do it themselves, [like Math users did](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19106/147263).