# What is up with all the "printer support number" posts?

Tags: discussion, spam, spam-detection

While I was on the meta asking [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258391/278094), I saw 8 of those printer support number posts (I flagged 7). They get handled quickly enough by the community flags, but is there any way to block whoever is behind all of those?

Here is an example of what (for anyone that has not seen it) is going on.
[image: spam printer support posts]

Comment: FYI, [you got reported](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3555422#3555422).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258317/the-body-of-my-post-cant-contain-82-213963/

Comment: @David That was a bot detecting spam. If it finds certain words in your question, it's gonna post a chat message raising a warning about your post. I suspect *support* was the case this time.

Comment: As best I could see (as a bystander that is) there was one user who posted several of them. It's just your typical spam formula. Maybe SE should look out for posts that have repeating symbols (I assume they already do), telephone numbers, specific terms (`{brand} printer {tech}? support`), or other potentially "spammy" terms. (According to that log, SE already has a comprehensive spam catching system.)

Comment: @EBrown, that's a bot written by [users](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), not SE itself.

Comment: Tim Post said it's a botnet. Whatever the case is, it feels that majority of new posts on meta.SE is tech support spam.

Comment: @Andy If it's not an SE spam catcher, perhaps SE should implement some more effective heuristics and drop questions that meet certain criterion into a specific queue. Or delete certain ones altogether.

Comment: Some context on this spam: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295964/reduce-usefulness-of-posting-spam-to-stack-overflow/295998#comment202106_295964 (see the rest of that discussion for more). It's a group that's been attacking SO for months and has spread to other sites. Even blocking techniques that stopped other distributed spammers aren't slowing them down. An attempt at a blacklist for their content didn't quite go as expected: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258317/the-body-of-my-post-cant-contain-82-213963

Comment: @EBrown - you are underestimating how cunning these spammers are. `pr1nter` `5upport`? `p-r-i-n-t-e-r`?

Comment: @Oded Not at all. Any capable programmer could easily make adjustments for certain structure. Hell even with my limited skills in regular expressions I could probably come up with something that was moderately tolerant.

Comment: @EBrown - thanks for calling me incapable ;) - [I've tried](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258317/the-body-of-my-post-cant-contain-82-213963). These guys kept changing the format enough every time to evade the regex. And at a certain stage it got so wide that it caught legitimate users out.

Comment: @EBrown such as `/.*/`? original http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258317/the-body-of-my-post-cant-contain-82-213963#comment842102_258340

Comment: @Oded My mistake, poor choice of wording. I wrote it on my phone while standing in Kroger, and didn't do my usual vocab-check (only spelling/grammar). What I mean to say, is that perhaps you guys are going about it wrongly. I don't know the specific code/regex/logic you currently use, but perhaps (not to insinuate you are a bad/incapable programmer) you should look at it from a different point of view. How do you know (as a person) that these questions are spam?

Comment: @EBrown - believe me that we _are_ looking at alternatives. Most of the signals that work well for other spammers don't seem to work on these, though we are certainly looking at options (don't forget that we need these checks to be quick and CPU cheap, given our scale).

Comment: @Oded do you have any insight into how the spammer(s) are effortlessly getting around captchas?

Comment: @CarrieKendall - some of these are people, not bots, and most spammers that get through (bots or otherwise) are registered accounts (so don't usually get a captcha)

Comment: Oh, I thought even new registered users got captchas. Either way, that's pretty crazy that they'd enlist actual people when they are producing pretty low quality, noticeable spam

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We've leaned harder on some of our existing spam blocking infrastructure (mostly to do with adding spam keywords to a dictionary).

I've been monitoring the spam block logs as well as the deleted posts here on MSE and am happy to report that for the time being, this measure has worked well.

By which I mean none of the printer spam has gotten through in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 17):

That's a persistent spammer.  Just keep flagging them as spam when you see them; MSE is active enough that most of them get shut down in under a minute.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: Interestingly, the [latest one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258427/146015) had a link to a [legit looking profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/296007/deepak-basnal) - is the spam bot getting good enough to create realistic profiles or are user's machines compromised in some way?

Comment: @slugster hmm, good question.  (I was too late to see the profile you linked.)  Presumably if those accounts had any other worthwhile activity SE would respond differently (suspend rather than destroy, I'd guess), so if compromised, we're talking about accounts that people bothered to set up but then didn't use.  Of course, it's possible that the spammers are simply scraping and copying profiles...

Comment: @slugster Realistic in the sense of having a regular name and a picture of a person? Most of spam accounts are like that. The image is usually a stock image from somewhere.